# Rename a file or directory shortcut in jupyter lab?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm using jupyter lab.but everytime when i touch a new file or directory it default names Untitle.I have to click it and select "rename".

Is there a shortcut to rename a file or a directory? i have search this question in google but i didn't find what i want.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to select the file and rename it.

You can give desired name just after a notebook it created or while it's open.Right Click on the tab where `Untitled`(in my case it is `Untitled1`) is written, in top left corner and select **`Rename Notebook`**.

[image]

It will open a popup text box.

[image]

change the name and click on RENAME.

Comment: My situation is not the same, i'm using jupyter lab,the evolution of the Jupyter notebook, so things are different.

Comment: @Hsgao sorry. missed that lab part.  Updated it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. this works, but still a little  tedious, just like what i say in the question.

Comment: I would like something like Crtl+R shortcut to rename my file or directory. anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to enable the shortcut by going Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts and add descriptions as below (and hit the save button at the upper right).

```
"command": "docmanager:rename",
"keys": [
    "Ctrl R"
],
"selector": "body"
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHenI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem. I found the settings in using my jupyter-themer 
from the Menu: Help-> Edit Keyboard Shortcuts -> rename notebook.
[see image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mi4r.png)